# RCS iteration such that the RCS limit is semi-proper

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

For a countable ordinal $\eta$ and an ordinal $\gamma$ let $\langle P_\alpha, \dot{Q}_\alpha \colon \alpha < \gamma \rangle$ be an RCS iteration with RCS limit $P_\gamma$, such that

- $\Vdash_\alpha \dot{Q}_\alpha$ is $\eta$-semi-proper;
- $\Vdash_{\alpha +1} \vert P_\alpha \vert \leqslant \aleph_1$.

Is then the RCS limit $P_\gamma$ also $\eta$-semi-proper?

Comment: Isn't this what Shelah's iteration theorem for RCS says?

Comment: If you ignore the $\eta$, or set $\eta = 1$, then it's Shelah's theorem. Of course, increasing $\eta$ only strengthens the hypothesis.

Comment: Sorry, I am not so familiar with the terminology. Do you mean to ask whether $P_\gamma$ is $\eta$-semi-proper?